# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProdReleaseAssets'

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting this error while creating appbundle in a flutter projet using the command `flutter build appbundle`

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDevReleaseAssets'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:devReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not determine artifacts for com.github.topjohnwu.libsu:core:3.1.2: Skipped due to earlier error 

BUILD FAILED in 5m 21s
```

The flutter sdk version used is `3.0.1` .

Answer (score 0):

Try again with flutter clean it works for me.

Comment: I have tried it. But the result is same.